# PHP - trying to add two string numbers together, but I can't figure out how

Tags: php, math, addition

I currently have the variable:

```
$harryVerJina = "1+2";
```

and I'm trying to add it to another random integer:

```
$baldVerJina = $harryVerJina + 3;
```

the result always seems to be 4, when it should be 6. I'm aware that php usually only takes the first 'int' in a string, but is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: remove the quotes 

$harryVerJina = (1+2);

Comment: @ATechGuy i now thats possible, but i need to figure out a solution to this specific concept for a larger scope of my project (which involves pulling an arithmetic equation through a curl)

Comment: @jameslin use eval() or parse it's arithmetic operators

Comment: Lol... are those production `vars`?